# How to create a file in Linux through javascript?

Tags: javascript, linux

I want to create, open, edit and save files in JavaScript on Linux.

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

I tried with this but that is only for the Windows platform.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's this for? Can't you use a server-side language? Browsers are typically sandboxed, this seems more suited for the back-end.

Comment: If you are not willing to try another languege, you could always use node.js or adobe air.

Comment: If this is clientside, refer to [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16388634/1729885). Otherwise clarify your platform more specifically.